# Possible to put css rule on an element when a seperate element exists?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have a scss file and I want to check if a certain element is present on the page and if it is then I want to hide another element.

roughly:

```
.thisElementExist + elementExists{
  .anotherElement: {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

I know I can do this in javascript but Im wondering if this can be done in a scss file only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with SASS nor CSS. SASS is strictly a declarative language; you cannot access the state of other elements without javascript.

However, it's very simple using js:

```
const elementOne = document.getElementById('elementOne')
const elementTwo = document.getElementById('elementTwo')

if (elementOne.style.display == 'none') {
    elementTwo.classList.add('your-style');
}else {
    elementTwo.classList.remove('your-style');
}
```

With React, you can have it run automatically by putting it inside an [effect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

```
useEffect(() => {
    const elementOne = document.getElementById('elementOne')
    const elementTwo = document.getElementById('elementTwo')

    if (elementOne.style.display == 'none') {
        elementTwo.classList.add('your-style');
    }else {
        elementTwo.classList.remove('your-style');
    }
});
```